# Angular interpolation not getting data

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I have an angular app that I'm trying to get data to show in the HTML by using interpolation, but the data isn't coming through. I have other places in my project that I'm using interpolation but they aren't getting data from a subscription. My .ts file looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent implement OnInit, OnDestroy {
    info: Information = new Information();
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.getStatus().subscribe(x =>
            this.info = x;
            console.log(this.info); returns data
        });
        console.log(this.info); returns undefined
    }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<h4>Information</h4>
<p>App Info: <span>{{ info.a }}</span></p>
<p>More App Info: <span>{{ info.b }}</span></p>
```

Why am I getting undefined for in my HTML where the interpolation is, and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could be several things. I'm suspicious of what's happening in the `Information()` ctor. As well as the `getStatus()` method. And `ngOnInit` since it runs before rendering the template. Could you provide the relevant parts of those 3? Also what version of Angular are you on?

Comment: Add a boolean `isLoaded` and assign it to `true` inside the `subscribe` block. Then wrap everything in your template with an `*ngIf="isLoaded"` and you will be good to go. The thing here is that `console.log(this.info)` that is outside the `subscribe` block is executed **first**, because the subscription is happening to an operation that is async.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly were you able to get `undefined` for `this.info` in that `console.log`? `new Information()` gets called before we enter the body of the ctor, so it's perplexing that the OP is getting `undefined` at that point, unless something messy is going on in the `Information` constructor. My recommendation was going to be to avoid explicit subscriptions, let an observable be an observable--otherwise you need to worry about cleaning up the orphaned subscription bloating memory, anyway. But I think we need more info to at least reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to use `info` before it is set.  The subscription runs asynchronously, so you cannot expect it to be ready by the end of the constructor.  A common solution is to use an asynchronous pipe, e.g.

```
info: Observable<Information>;

void ngOnInit() {
    this.info = this.myService.getStatus();
}
```

and then in your template

```
<h4>Information</h4>
<p>App Info: <span>{{ (info | async).a }}</span></p>
<p>More App Info: <span>{{ (info | async).b }}</span></p>
```

Comment: suppose i am running through table of product and have to pass product id to get quantity how does that work ?

Comment: i am doing something {{ GetProductQuantity(productID) }} and {{GetAverageProductRating() }} how that work i have table where i am running through loop of  product detail